# 'result' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

Tags: swift, access-control, swift-custom-framework

I want to create custom framework for universal API request using URLSession. So I have used [this](https://github.com/GabeTheCoder/SpeedyNetworking) link. I will be using this project as a custom framework. So to use that I have changed its access specifier by `open` .And using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMYxlkOE35k)link I have imported it in my project. And I have done the following code to call post request

```
import iOSCoreFramework

func callBySpeedyNetworking2() {
    let trylogin = login(username: "****", password: "***")
    SpeedyNetworking.removeToken()
    SpeedyNetworking.postUrl(url: URL(string: GlobalConstants.loginFullURL), model: trylogin) { (response) in
        if !response.success {
            // show a network error
            print("network error ",response.error)
            return
        }
        // successful
        print("RESPONSE 1 ------------> ")
        dump(response.result(model: ModelResponse.self))
        dump(response.jsonResults(model: ModelResponse.self))
    }
}
```

But it's giving me an error for 'success', 'error' and on the following lines:

```
dump(response.result(model: ModelResponse.self))
dump(response.jsonResults(model: ModelResponse.self))
```

From various links I have made changes in `SpeedyResponse` class by the following

```
public class SpeedyResponse {

public var success : Bool!
public var statusCode = 0
public var error: Error?
public var data: Data?
public init (success : Bool, statusCode : Int,error :  Error, data : Data){
    self.success = success
    self.statusCode = statusCode
    self.error = error
    self.data = data
}

public init(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {
    self.error = error
    self.data = data

    if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
    }

    success = statusCode == 200 && error == nil && data != nil ? true : false
}

public func jsonResults<T>(model: T.Type) -> T? {
    if !success { return nil }
    guard let responseData = data else { return nil }

    do {
        return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData) as? T
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}

public func result<T: Decodable>(model: T.Type) -> T? {
    if !success { return nil }
    guard let responseData = data else { return nil }

    do {
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(model, from: responseData)
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}

}
```

But still it wasn't fixed.

Comment: I am facing same issue. Anyone can know the actual issue?

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem here is inside your `struct` all variables and methods are declared automatically with its scope as `internal`. So when you create a type like this:

```
public class Human {
    let foo: String
    let bar: String
}
```

You will not be able to access both `foo` and `bar` because they are actually declared as:

```
public class Human {
    internal let foo: String
    internal let bar: String
}
```

To fix this just add the access modifier to `public`.

---

In that sense your new model should look like this

```
public class SpeedyResponse {

    public var success: Bool!
    public var statusCode = 0
    public var error: Error?
    public var data: Data?

    public init(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {
        self.error = error
        self.data = data

        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
        }

        success = statusCode == 200 && error == nil && data != nil ? true : false
    }

    public func jsonResults<T>(model: T.Type) -> T? {
        if !success { return nil }
        guard let responseData = data else { return nil }

        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData) as? T
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }

    public func result<T: Decodable>(model: T.Type) -> T? {
        if !success { return nil }
        guard let responseData = data else { return nil }

        do {
            return try JSONDecoder().decode(model, from: responseData)
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank for your response. I have done this also ,but not succeed

Comment: I have made the suggested changes . Please check but still getting the same error

Comment: Are you sure you're using an updated version of the framework you just created?

Comment: Without more context on how you actually setup your project I won't be able to do much help here. The above code should work.